# Not able to find a solution for the issue:, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS

Tags: java

I am creating below JSONObject and sending in Post method:

```java
public JSONObject notesRequest(String memberNumber) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false); 
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    
    JSONObject reqWarn = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject MessageVO= new JSONObject();
    MessageVO.put("memberNumber", memberNumber);
    MessageVO.put("dType", "USAA");
    MessageVO.put("requesId", REQ_SRC_ID);
    MessageVO.put("company", "TXT");
    MessageVO.put("retentionDays", "15");
    MessageVO.put("Date", "");
    MessageVO.put("summary", "Notes");
    MessageVO.put("Text", "Details");
    reqWarn.put("Message", MessageVO);
    return reqWarn;
}
```

I am posting to the API using below post method

```java
.post(Entity.json(notesRequest));
```

When I call post method, I am getting the below error:

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:  No serializer found
> for class org.json.usaa.JSONObject and no properties discovered to
> create BeanSerializer  (to avoid exception, disable
> SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )

I tried all the different solutions but stuck for a week without any solution. Appreciate your thoughts and help on this. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use `JSONObject` but a custom class that represents the JSON you want to be serialized instead.

Comment: I tried that too. I created Java object with custom class and then converted from Java object to JSON object. Still the error persists.

Comment: The thing is that you shouldn't convert it to `JSONObject`. I guess that the library you are using to perform the POST call does that on your behalf.

Comment: When I send Java object directly, it doesn't take and the API team said that I need to send only JSONObject.

Comment: But I guess the API is a REST API that takes JSON. JSON is just text formated in a specific way.